# How to stop the notification when te count stop?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i stop the notification when counts ends?
I would like to notify just one time.
The notification dont stop, still in eternal loop.
I think the cause is the "showNotification" variable inside the funciton "count", but i cant resolve.

```
function count(){
    if(seconds > 0){
       if(toCount == true){
            seconds--;
            remseconds = seconds % 60;
            minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

            if(remseconds < 10){
                remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
            }

            if(minuts < 10){
                minuts = "0" + minuts;
            }

            counter.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
       }
    }
    else{
        counter.innerHTML = "Done!";
        btn.style.opacity = '0';
         showNotification();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `count()`? If it's just an interval, call `clearInterval` when the count is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setTimeout** function.

Display an alert box after 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds):

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```